# Cannot create virtualenv instance in python 2.7.5 because of pip installation error

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, pip

I'm trying to follow the directions on the Flask installation website but I encountered an error after I used "sudo easy_install virtualenv" to install virtual environment. Not sure

```
Opals-MacBook-Pro:~ opalkale$ mkdir myproject
Opals-MacBook-Pro:~ opalkale$ cd myproject
Opals-MacBook-Pro:myproject opalkale$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /Users/opalkale/myproject/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 2696, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 429, in __init__
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 443, in add_entry
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1722, in find_in_zip
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1298, in has_metadata
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1614, in _has
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1488, in _zipinfo_name
AssertionError: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO is not a subpath of /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 820, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 956, in install_wheel
'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 898, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/opalkale/myproject/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried using pip to install virtualenv?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I tried sudo pip install virtualenv and I think the  problem is that it doesn't know what pip is. I've been trying to download pip and i've been having problems

Comment: have a look at http://brew.sh then you can do `brew install python`, that will give you pip as well.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I downloaded homebrew and then installed python, but I am getting the same error as above?

Comment: @ Opal, you're using `/usr/local/bin/pip` to do `sudo pip install virtualenv`?

Comment: I just opened up my terminal and ran `sudo pip install virtualenv`. Am I installing it in the wrong place?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44471/discussion-between-opal-and-edgar-aroutiounian)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is logged as an [issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/524) with the recently released virtualenv 1.11. I had similar issues on Windows with this release.

I believe installing virtualenv 1.10.1 will let you continue working until this issue is addressed.

Comment: The issue you mention is now closed but it seems that the problem still exists in 1.11.1. See https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/550. It works ok for me after going back to 1.10

Comment: Yes, and someone already opened a new issue: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/552

Comment: On Ubuntu, just ran sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv and it installed virtualenv-1.11.2. virtualenv worked after that.

Comment: Same issue on Windows (with virtualenv 1.11.2). Reverting to 1.10.1 did the trick

Comment: Whilst the linked issue above is marked as closed I'm still finding issues with this.

Comment: Downgrading virtualenv to ``1.10.1`` gets me back to a working environment. +1

Comment: Still finding the same issue. I also downgraded to `1.10.1` and everything worked. Thanks Miguel! +1

Comment: Yep, run this: `sudo easy_install virtualenv==1.10.1`.

Answer (score 0):

As timborden said in a comment: version 1.11.2 (of 2014-01-26) fixes this.

"Fixed easy_install installed virtualenvs by updated pip to 1.5.2"

See changelog at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv